# Apply condition on list of lists in a loop and get lists of list as output

Tags: python, list, loops

This piece of code does the job but I don't understand how it works.
As I reset the content of list_temp every time before it reaches list_output.
How come list_output is not empty at the end?

Btw, what's a better way to code this?

```
list_input = [['url1','1. a','b','c'],['url2','1. d','f','g']]

list_output = []
counter = -1

for i in list_input:
    list_temp = []
    counter = counter + 1
    list_output.append(list_temp)

    for j in list_input[counter]:
        if 'url' in j:
            list_temp.append(j)
        elif '1.' in j:    
            list_temp.append(j)

print(list_output)

>>>
[['url1', '1. a'], ['url2', '1. d']]
```

Comment: ```list_temp = []``` creates new list, then it's appended to list_output, then it filled with data. list_temp is the same object which just appended, so when it's filled, appended piece filled too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
list_temp = []
```

This line does 2 things:

- create an empty `list` object (let's call this the object)
- make the name `list_temp` point to that object (let's call this the name)

```
list_output.append(list_temp)
```

This line appends the **object** to the output list.

The next time that this happens:

```
list_temp = []
```

A **new** object is allocated, and the name `list_temp` is made to point to this new object instead. The other object that was created previously is untouched. Since that object was added to the output list already, it stays there.

Hope that clears up the confusion. `list_temp` & `[]` are not the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

adding a "tangible" way to see for yourself what @rdas explains in his excellent answer:

you can use [`id()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id) to get a unique identifier for an object (as an implementation details it's usually the address in memory where this object sits).

add `print(id(list_temp))` after your `list_temp = []`, you can see for yourself it is indeed a different object every time.

```py
list_input = [['url1','1. a','b','c'],['url2','1. d','f','g']]

list_output = []
counter = -1

for i in list_input:
    list_temp = []
    print(id(list_temp)) # added this line, nothing else changed
    counter = counter + 1
    list_output.append(list_temp)

    for j in list_input[counter]:
        if 'url' in j:
            list_temp.append(j)
        elif '1.' in j:    
            list_temp.append(j)

print(list_output)
```

example output:

```
59792584
59792712
[['url1', '1. a'], ['url2', '1. d']]
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by a friend, a more elegant way to code this:

```
list_output = []

for url in list_input:
        list_output.append([item for 
            item in url if ('url' in item) or ('1.' in item)])

print(list_output)
```